# Поставить ли запятую перед союзом "и" в сложном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, сложное-предложение

Уважаемые знатоки, я слегка запуталась в структуре сложного предложения. Нужна ли запятая после слова «есть»?

> Но Митт выплескивает на сестру все, что скопил, все, что есть и даже то, чего еще нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Союз И тут ни при чем. Мы обособляем придаточное "что есть", поэтому запятая ставится.

Comment: А мне все же кажется, что союз И очень даже при чем. Пунктуация здесь зависит от того, что этот союз соединяет. Вот только что он соединяет? А?

Comment: Уберем придаточные: **Но Митт выплескивает на сестру всё, всё и даже то.** Видите, что соединяет союз И? Однородные прямые дополнения.

Comment: Елена, запятая здесь нужна. Не нужна  запятая,  если есть однородные придаточные, например:   Но Митт выплескивает на сестру все, что скопил, что есть и чего еще нет.

Comment: Вот теперь дошло! Сомнений не осталось.)))